# How to import module (loadChildren) with condittion in the RouterModule?

Tags: angular, routes

I want to dynamically import module (lazy loading) in the `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` depending on the condition which I get in the Http-response.
Something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
    {
    path: 'user-page',
    loadChildren: () => {
      if (SomeHttpRespCondition) {
        return import('./coach-page/coach-page.module')
          .then(m => m.CoachPageModule);
      } else {
        return import('./user-page/user-page.module')
          .then(m => m.UserPageModule);
      }
    }
  },
  ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would move it to a route guard with a `canLoad`.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz as I understand correctly ```canLoad``` decides if a module can be loaded lazily. But how to import another module instead? Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have any logic in routes configuration, in routes config you simply bind `/user-page` to `UserPageModule` and `/coach-page` to `CoachPageModule`.

Then you need to implement guards for both routes (`CanLoad` or `CanActivate` does not matter much in this case) that will (make request probably and) check whether user really has an access to target page, and if he doesn't you can redirect him to the right page.

Guards should be on both routes to prevent user from accessing not available for him page. For redirection you can use `Router` service or you can return `UrlTree` object (that points to redirected page) from the guard and angular will process it and redirect user.